# AngularJS + Java Rest API + MySQL. Diacritics won't encode properly

Tags: java, angularjs, api, rest, diacritics

I have a problem that I can't solve, and it is about encoding diacritics (ex: ă Ă â Â î Î ş Ş ţ Ţ). The problem seems to be somewhere between the client and the server, but I don't understand how, because I am setting the charset correctly.

This is the code:

**AngularJS side**

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: serverUrl + 'wr/users/update',
        data: JSON.stringify(content),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }});
```

**Server - Java Glassfish 4.1 Rest API**

```
@Path("/update")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public String update(String data) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    try {
        JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject(data);
        System.out.println("[dataJson] " + dataJson.toString());
        if (!dataJson.has("sessionId") ||
            !dataJson.has("user")) {
                result.put("success", "false");
                result.put("errorMessage", "Fields missing.");
        } else {
            int userId = (int) em.createNamedQuery("Session.findAuthorBySession")
                .setParameter("session", dataJson.getString("sessionId"))
                .getSingleResult();
            Users user = this.find(userId);

            JSONObject new_user = dataJson.getJSONObject("user");
            user.setBio(new_user.getString("bio"));
            super.edit(user);

            result.put("success", "true");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    return result.toString();
}
```

If I print the content before the http post call it looks ok ('ă Ă â Â î Î ş Ş ţ Ţ') and when it arrives to the Rest API, it looks as follows: '? ? â Â î Î ? ? ? ?'.

Maybe it's something I missed, but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

Why does this happen ?

Thank you.

**EDIT 1**

As @JoseM suggested, I looked at the request that was sent to the server and everything looks ok. If somehow I am missing something, this is the request:

**Request headers**

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ro;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:95
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:lastMessageSeen=151; hideBanner=true; session=7d7f5c64faf243cfbb469641d4a8c9a2
Host:app.meritwork.com
Origin:http://app.meritwork.com
Referer:http://app.meritwork.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
```

**Request payload**

```
{sessionId: "7d7f5c64faf243cfbb469641d4a8c9a2", user: {bio: "ă Ă â Â î Î ş Ş ţ Ţ"}}
```

**EDIT 2**

As about the json java decoder library, I printed the string before constructing the json object, and it is all the same; the json library isn't the problem.

Comment: Look at the network requests tab in your and check if the request that was sent out actually went out correctly.  If it did, then maybe it's something else in between or maybe even the library code (see this bug report for a similar issue with another library https://github.com/mulesoft/apikit/issues/46 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged a little the code, it seems that the logger from Java didn't print correctly the UTF-8 chars, the issue persists anyway, but I opened another post for that. The links is here: [RestAPI in Java with MySQL DB: issue on storing data with diacritics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720688/restapi-in-java-with-mysql-db-issue-on-storing-data-with-diacritics)